# POST Method not working with jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a phonegapp app. Have a simple login form in **action.php** file and for test purpose I am just printing the submit variable in other file **see.php**.

Issue is that if I include following line of code in **action.php** then submitted variables from form are not getting printed:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But If I remove the above line from **action.php**, form is getting submitted properly and input variables are getting printed in **see.php**

action.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>Application</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" /> 
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,vietnamese,latin-ext,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head> 
<body> 

    <form action="see.php" method = "post">
        <label for="Cedula" style="font-size:10px; color:#FFF; text-shadow:none">Cedula</label>
        <input type="text" name="usr" id="usr" value="username" data-clear-btn="true">
        <label for="Contrasena" style="font-size:10px; color:#FFF; text-shadow:none">Contrasena</label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" value="password" data-clear-btn="true">
        <input type="submit" data-role="button" style="font-weight:100" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

see.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$uid = $_POST['usr'];
$upwd = $_POST['pwd'];

echo $uid;
echo "<br>";
echo $upwd;
echo "<br>";


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in console ( network ) , see.php is being called and values of post are printed . You can turn your firebug ON and check the results ..

In jQuery Mobile, form submissions are automatically handled using Ajax whenever possible

To submit the form normally you can use data-ajax="false" in form

```
<form data-ajax="false" action="" method="">
```

Comment: Absolutely Correct! Works like a charm now. Thanks! it was a great help. [*****]