# BootStrap/JavaScript casuing html not able to POST data

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, post

I'm trying to Post valuable from a html page to a php page.

I have went through the code and try to troubleshooting, at the end I found out that if I remove one of the JS from the html page (`<scrpit></scrpit>`), I will be able to post data, but then the lay out would be mess up. I have no idea how to solve this problem, I only know that it was caused by the js script.

Here's my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Meta -->
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
<!-- Meta End -->

<!-- Title -->
<title>Book Now - 多伦多第一接送团队</title>
<!-- Title -->

<!-- Include -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0 /jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Icnlude End -->

</head>

<!-- Body -->
<body>

<form action="BookNowDone.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" value="Sumbit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And Here's my php page

```
<?php

//Get Value From BookNow.html
$name=$_POST["name"];

echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, my original code is Name: <input type="text" name="name">, its just mess up when I post it here

Comment: end your input tag with />

Comment: There is no space within the jquery stylesheet url, I kinda mess it up when I upload >.<  any idea how i would be able to edit my thread? thanks

Comment: Does this post help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424403/post-method-not-working-with-jquery-mobile-1-4-0-min-js

Comment: It doesn't work when I end the input tag with /> either. I have tried it. On the internet it says it is not nesscessary to have a slash

Comment: its xhtml conform so for better results you the slash version, you should also add a slash to you submit button ;)

Comment: have you checked if all js file are found and no 404 occurs?

Comment: @blex I double checked my code, it is only 1 n. As I said when  i post code on stackoverflow i got kinda mess up, but thanks

Comment: @ChaosClown Yes I've checked. As I said If I remove the javascript that I include, it would work. I don't know why

Comment: @ChaosClown my js file are local. and im developing with zend studio, if it's not found it would show error.

Comment: I also tried using method="get". I can see the valuable are in the url, but still not able to echo

Comment: you could try print_r($_REQUEST) but it should already work